# SAXParseException in one case but not in the other when using same xml

Tags: java, xml, servlets, xml-parsing

this is my first question here so tell me anything that's missing so i can add it.

Now, we have a deploy that uses tomcat 7,there we have 5 servlets that modify some data in a SQLServer DB, based on several .XML that are read from five .jar (one for each servlet) and all those .jar are originated by the .war,  i'm trying to modify it so it stops working as a servlet, and you can run the modifications locally.

I have the same configuration in both scenarios (via tomcat and on my local "run.bat") and both of them use the same libs to read the files, so no chance that one of them is reading an .XML that's not validated, but on the local scenario i get "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog"

this is the line that generates the problem ("file" is the path to the file):

```
    public void procesarArchivo(String file) throws SAXException, IOException, SAXException {
        xr.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(leerXML(file))));
        /* i do stuff here*/
    }

    public String leerXML(String XMLName) {
        String line = "";
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(XMLName);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            br.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            sb.append(e.getMessage());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Here you have the servlet .log file with everithing working fine:

```
INFO  [Thread-1  ] - [[Cargando_reglas_del_sistema]]...
DEBUG [Thread-1  ] - [[Procesando_Archivo]]: com/systech/reglas/xml/reglas_0.xml
DEBUG [Thread-1  ] - [[Leyendo_regla]]: CTRLDOCURE.sql
/*... and so on with all the .sql*/
```

Here you can see the local .log file (using the same libs as before) with the error, when it says "procesando archivo" means that the file has been found, but then it tries to read it:

```
INFO  [main   ] - [[Cargando_reglas_del_sistema]]...
DEBUG [main   ] - Procesando Archivo: com/systech/reglas/xml/reglas_0.xml
ERROR [main   ] - org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; El contenido no está permitido en el prólogo.
```

What i don't understand is why one of them works and the other one doesn't when it's the same code being executed.

Any help will be appreciated, and sorry for the poor english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not very sure why, but this was the answer:

I have a config file with this parameters:

```
resReglas=./wardir/WEB-INF/lib/reglas.jar
resVistas=./wardir/WEB-INF/lib/vistas.jar
```

aparently the first one wasn't working properly, it found the file but with some error, i changed:

```
String reglasJar =props.getProperty("resReglas");
```

for this:

```
String reglasJar =System.getProperty("user.dir")+ props.getProperty("resReglas").replaceFirst(".","");
```

and it worked!